# Nested loops on array of arrays to update ejs views

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a picks array that gets passed to my dashboards.ejs file.  The picks array consists of inner arrays that each represent a user in my database. This user array consists of objects for each week of the regular season in the NFL, each user can have many bullets which is why the object is structured like so.  See the commented picks array code below.

I am now trying to update the views to show which picks the users make in a table, and am wondering how to get this done.  Essentially I will need to run a for each loop over the picks array, than a nested loop over each users array, and then another loop over the table rows.

So for example, the week-1 pick for jojo-0, jojo-1, jojo-2 will need to match up to the table row  where the id == user.bulletNumber, and also where the td's class is equal to the current objects week.

Iteration is really tricky to me and has been for as long as I began trying to program, so maybe that is why I cant figure this out.  Any resources to help with iteration would be great.  Also, it seems to me like as many users get added, lets say 200, this task will take a long time.  Is this the best way to do what I am trying to do?  Or is there a better way

### [Github Repo](https://github.com/JordanVera/survivor_league_app)

### All Users Picks Array

```
[
  [
    {"week-1":{"jojo-0":"CLE" /* 1st bullet pick */,"jojo-1":"CLE" /* 2nd bullet pick */,"jojo-2":"CLE" /* 3rd bullet pick */}},
    {"week-2":{"jojo-0":"CIN","jojo-1":"CAR","jojo-2":"CAR"}}
  ],
  [
    // this user only has two bullets
    {"week-1":{"Jordan-0":"CAR","Jordan-1":"CHI"}},
    {"week-2":{"Jordan-0":"CIN","Jordan-1":"DEN"}}
  ]
]
```

### Dashboard.ejs table

```
<tr id="jojo-0">
  <td class="week-1"></td>
  <td class="week-2"></td>
  <td class="week-3"></td>
  <!-- All the way to week 17 -->
</tr>
<tr id="jojo-1">
  <td class="week-1"></td>
  <td class="week-2"></td>
  <td class="week-3"></td>
  <!-- All the way to week 17 -->
</tr>
<tr id="jojo-2">
  <td class="week-1"></td>
  <td class="week-2"></td>
  <td class="week-3"></td>
  <!-- All the way to week 17 -->
</tr>
```